# Terminal Services Buttons Stuck (mstsc)

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services

After connecting to a remote server via mstsc, the window opens fine and everything in full-screen mode, but the close/minimize/restore buttons get stuck. I.e they do not respond to any action (they don't change when you mouseover them or do anything when you click on them). However, I am running an extended desktop, so when I click on the desktop on the other monitor the buttons start working. It's a perplexing problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unpin the menu bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: Tried this :( It didn't work.